# cordova printer plugin: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'printer' of undefined

Tags: cordova, printing, phonegap-plugins

I tried downloading the example for cordova printer plugin [cordova-plugin-printer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer/tree/example) to use it in my phonegap project.I have put the corresponding js in the folder and there are no errors when I click inspect element. But when I click the buttons it shows an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'printer' of undefined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.print

I already installed the plugin but I can't get it to work. I am quite unsure about what to put in the feature tag also. Could it be the problem?

### EDIT

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 distributed with this work for additional information
 regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 specific language governing permissions and limitations
 under the License.
 -->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Printer Plugin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Printer Plugin</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <a id="check" href="#" class="button grey">Check</a>
                <a id="pick" href="#" class="button grey">Pick</a>
                <a id="print" href="#" class="button orange">Print</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="copyright">
            Â© 2016 appPlant<br/>
            Made with <g-emoji alias="yum" fallback-src="https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f60b.png">ðŸ˜‹</g-emoji> from Leipzig
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

actually this code came from the sample given and i just tried running it and failed. i think the plugin cannot be read

Comment: sample code please...